# Excluding resource or ignore variable in Terraform module

Tags: terraform

I have Terraform module that is being used by two environments:

```
module "x" {
  source = "../modules/x"

  api_key = var.api_key
  token   = var.token
  env     = var.env
  list    = var.list

}
```

`list` var is being used in production environment only.

Then I have a resource in module `x` based on `for_each` loop:

```
resource "some_resource" "some_resource_name" {
  for_each = var.env == "production" ? var.list : {}
...
```

variable is a map of objects:

```
variable "list" {
  type = map(object({
    x = string
  }))
}
```

Module structure:

```
── modules
│   └── x
│       ├── resources.tf
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── non-production
│   ├── main.tf
│   └── variables.tf
└── production
    ├── main.tf
    └── variables.tf
```

First code snippet is from `production/main.tf`

While it is fine for `"production"` environment it is expecting `var.list` variable to be present in another non-production environment.

How can I prevent non-production environment from using/requesting it?

Comment: You could use just one list and change values according to the environment.

Comment: Also, where would `var.list_2` be used?

Comment: @MarkoE Both lists are being used in production environment, the thing is that non-production environment expects these variables to be present and not empty.

Comment: Can you add the example with list2 to the question so I can answer?

Comment: @MarkoE both `list_1` and `list_2` are being used in resources in production environment only. They both have the same structure just different data. I've added example of list variable.

Comment: I didn't think the variable structure, rather the resource where it is used.

Comment: @MarkoE Let's simplify it. There is only one var.list that is going to be used in production environment only. I've added also directory structure to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top level, just declare a default value for `list`. Like this:

```
variable "list" {
  description = "My List value"
  type        = list
  default     = []
}
```

Although it looks like you are calling it a list, but it is actually a map, or  a set? In that case just have the default be `default = {}`

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I did that before but forgot to add `default = {}`. Thanks!